# Failure/Error: assigns(:posts).should eq([post])

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

post_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe Blog::PostsController do
  let!(:posts) { FactoryGirl.create_list(:post, 3) }
  let!(:post) { posts.first }
  describe "GET index" do
    it "renders the :index view" do
      get :index
      assigns(:posts).should eq([post])
      response.should render_template :index
    end
  end
 describe "GET show" do
  context "invalid post" do
    before do
      get :show, :id => 99
    end
    it "redirects to the 404 page" do
    response.should render_template(:file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html")
    end
  end
  context "valid post" do
    it "show page" do
      get :show, id: post
        assigns(:post).should eq(post)
        response.should render_template :show
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is my index action:

```
def index
    @posts = Post.all.order_by(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end
```

I'm getting this error:

```
1) Blog::PostsController GET index renders the :index view
 Failure/Error: assigns(:posts).should eq([post])

   expected: [#<Post _id: 517ebb98a616542f41000002, created_at: 2013-04-29 18:27:36 UTC, updated_at: 2013-04-29 18:27:36 UTC, image_filename: nil, impressions_count: nil, tags: ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3", "tag4"], _slugs: ["post-number-1"], title: "Post number 1", content: "[\"Maiores dolor illum distinctio eveniet perspiciatis necessitatibus consequatur. Dicta ratione repellat ullam sit sed inventore voluptatem. Possimus magni cum dolores rerum voluptas quibusdam. Sed rerum atque accusantium amet aut.\", \"Consequatur ab eum voluptatem voluptatem sit et. Natus soluta quam sed quasi vel odio assumenda. Nulla excepturi dicta voluptatem voluptas vel sit.\"]", image: nil, image_cache: nil, remove_image: nil, admin_id: "517ebb98a616542f41000001">]
        got: #<Mongoid::Criteria
     selector: {}
     options:  {:sort=>{"created_at"=>-1}, :limit=>9, :skip=>0}
     class:    Post
     embedded: false>


   (compared using ==)

   Diff:
   @@ -1,2 +1,6 @@
   -[#<Post _id: 517ebb98a616542f41000002, created_at: 2013-04-29 18:27:36 UTC, updated_at: 2013-04-29 18:27:36 UTC, image_filename: nil, impressions_count: nil, tags: ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3", "tag4"], _slugs: ["post-number-1"], title: "Post number 1", content: "[\"Maiores dolor illum distinctio eveniet perspiciatis necessitatibus consequatur. Dicta ratione repellat ullam sit sed inventore voluptatem. Possimus magni cum dolores rerum voluptas quibusdam. Sed rerum atque accusantium amet aut.\", \"Consequatur ab eum voluptatem voluptatem sit et. Natus soluta quam sed quasi vel odio assumenda. Nulla excepturi dicta voluptatem voluptas vel sit.\"]", image: nil, image_cache: nil, remove_image: nil, admin_id: "517ebb98a616542f41000001">]
   +#<Mongoid::Criteria
   +  selector: {}
   +  options:  {:sort=>{"created_at"=>-1}, :limit=>9, :skip=>0}
   +  class:    Post
   +  embedded: false>

 # ./spec/controllers/blog/posts_controller_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**My show action, pass the test. Where have I the error on index action?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoid doesn't fetch the data until it absolutely has to. So this means, when you do `Model.where` you get back a [`Mongoid::Criteria`](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html#queries) object. This class implements `count` and `each` (also includes `Enumerable`), so it usually behaves like an `Array`, but it is not. You need to convert it using `to_a`.

This should resolve the error:

```
describe "GET index" do
  it "renders the :index view" do
    get :index
    assigns(:posts).to_a.should match_array posts
    response.should render_template :index
  end
end
```

The reason your show action works, is that `Model.find`, and `Model.find_by` will return a single object, or raise an exception if that object does not exist; so Mongoid runs the query immediately.

Comment: Thank you, Now, I get the error with a extra element: `the extra elements were: [#<Post _id: 517f81ffa61654f343000004, created_at: 2013-04-30 08:34:07 UTC`,. Thank you very much!

Comment: Ah right, I see you had FactoryGirl create 3 posts. That makes sense. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are trying to compare different type of objects.

You can try to convert `assings[:posts]` like this:

```
assings[:posts].to_a.should eq([post])
```

But since the array is not the same, I think it will not work too.

So, you can try to verify if `post` is inside `assings[:post]`:

```
assings[:posts].should include(post)
```

Comment: Thank you, but with `assigns[:posts].should include(post)`, I get the same error